# Date and days for php programmation

Tags: php

I need help on a code dates.

I have a municipality that has certain days of office:

```
$Dispatch = array ( "Monday" , "Friday" , "Saturday" ) ;
```

offices 2 business days made ​​after the order then if I asked on Monday

should reach me on Wednesday but as Wednesday is not in the array of dates

shipments should reach me the nearest to that date bone on Friday ,

another example if I I ask for a day Saturday should reach me on Monday and is listed as deliverable .

```
$dias = array("Domingo","Lunes","Martes","Miercoles","Jueves","Viernes","Sabado");
        $meses = array("Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre");

$despacho = array("Lunes","Viernes","Sabado");
$dia_actual = $dias[date('w')];
$dia_actual_normal = $dias[date('w')+2];
if(in_array($dia_actual_normal,$despacho))
    {
        $actual = $dia_actual_normal;
    }
```

I have this but I don't know more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've slightly changed your code

```
// index of normal actual day
$i = (date('w')+2) % 6;
// find 1st ocurrence in despacho array
while ( ! in_array($dias[$i], $despacho))  $i =  ($i+1) % 6;
$actual = $dias[$i];
```

Comment: probe your code and it works fine but now probe other day , Tuesday , Saturday and Sunday , today is Wednesday, if most two days I should give as Friday but not on the list, you must give me Saturday . but when you run the code tells me Sunday.

why?

Comment: $dias = array("Domingo","Lunes","Martes","Miercoles","Jueves","Viernes","Sabado");
$meses = array("Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre");

  $despacho = array("Martes","Sabado","Domingo");
  $dia_actual = $dias[date('w')];
  $dia_actual_normal = $dias[date('w')+2];

  $i = (date('w')+2) % 6;
  // find 1st ocurrence in despacho array
  while ( ! in_array($dias[$i], $despacho))  $i =  ($i+1) % 6;
  $actual4 = $dias[$i];
  print_r($actual4);
  exit();

Comment: thanks, but look at : $despacho = array("Martes","Viernes","Sabado"); or $despacho = array("Tuesday","Friday","Saturday"); if I buy today, Wednesday should get out Friday and shows me the day Saturday .
Why is this?
only if there is the day in office, you should seek the day but nearest office. help me please

Answer (score 0):

Just add days to you business, until reach your desired day:

```
$desired_day = Datetime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2016-05-18');
$Dispatch = array ( "Monday" , "Friday" , "Saturday" );

$interval = DateInterval::createfromdatestring('+1 day');
while(!in_array($desired_day->format('l'), $Dispatch)) {
    $desired_day->add($interval);
}

return $desired_day->format('l');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$dias = array("Lunes","Martes","Miercoles","Jueves","Viernes","Sabado","Domingo");
        $meses = array("Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre");

        $despacho = array("Martes","Viernes","Sabado");
        $dia_actual = $dias[date('w')];
        $dia_actual_normal = $dias[date('w')+2];

        $i = (date('w')+2) % 6;
        // find 1st ocurrence in despacho array
        while ( ! in_array($dias[$i], $despacho))  $i =  ($i+1) % 6;
        $actual1 = $dias[$i];

print_r($actual1);
        exit();
```

But not work, because today is wednesday so it should be friday :S

Help me